# Swap function based on ai+b mod n

Tags: c++, c++11

I need a swap function which will swap based on the results which i get after computing ai+b mod n

For example i have a text : `"TEST"` and i want to swap based on `ai+b mod n`
say i get a result `ai+b mod n` as 2, 4, 1, 3 ie is my text after swap will be "ETTS" the letter at my first position will be at position 3, position 2 will be position 1, position 3 will be 4 and 4 will be 2.

The following code will generate the values for `ax+b mod n`, Need some help on how to swap the words in the file. Thanks in advance. Thanks

```
int main ()
{
    cout << "Enter values of a and b." << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << "Enter input file name." << endl;
    cin >> inputfile;

    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen (inputfile, "rb");
    if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
    else
    {
        fseek (pFile, 0, SEEK_END);   // non-portable
        sizeoffile = ftell (pFile);
        cout << sizeoffile << "\n";
        fclose (pFile);
    }

    n = sizeoffile / 32;
    cout << n << endl;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int message1 = ((a * i + b) % n);
        int c = message1;
        cout << c << endl;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: I see that you are swapping values, and I see you are using some formula ax+b mod n, but I do NOT see how the two are related.  Is the formula meant to generate the swapping rule?  And if so, wouldn't certain combinations such as a=2, b=0, n=4 fail?

Comment: The formula will just generate the values for the position which i have mentioned in my example. Depending on the values i need to swap the letters in the file. Yes it is going to fail the numbers have to be chosen in such a way that the formula does not fail.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second string, the same length as the first, and copy the (ai+b)'th character of the first string to the i'th position of the output.

Keep in mind that C++ starts counting at 0.